# How to test react component correctly?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Recently I am learning to test React with jest and enzyme, It seems hard to understand what a unit test is it, my code

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return <Nest value={this.state.value} handleChange={this.handleChange} />;
  }
}

export const Nest = props => {
  return <input value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange} />;
};

export default App;
```

and my test

```
import React from "react";
import App, { Nest } from "./nest";

import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";

it("should be goood", () => {
  const handleChange = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  wrapper.find("input").simulate("change", { target: { value: "test" } });
  expect(handleChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

IMO, the mocked `handleClick` will intercept the `handleClick` on `App`,

if this is totally wrong, what's the right way to use mock fn and test the `handleClick` be called.

**Another**: I search a lot, read the similar situations, seem like this is`contra-Unit Test`,
Probably I should test the two component separately, I can test both components,
test the
`<Nest value={value} handleChange={handleChange} />`
by pass the props manually, and then `handleChange`invoked by simulate `change`
it passed test.
but how can I test the connection between the two? 
I read

> some work is React Team's Work
>   ...

I don't know which parts I have to test in this case, and Which parts `react` already tested and don't need me to test. That's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the path of testing the `Nest` component in isolation first, passing your mocked `handleChange` as a prop, to verify that input changes are being propagated.

If you want to test the state part, then you can get the `instance` of your App class from enzyme and call that method directly:

```
it("should update the Nest value prop when change is received", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  const instance = wrapper.instance()
  instance.handleChange( { target: { value: "test" } })
  const nestComponent = wrapper.find("Nest").first()      
  expect(nestComponent).prop('value').toEqual('test');
});
```

This a very very basic, almost not needed to test piece of code, but it will get your test coverage up if that's what you're after.

Doc for instance: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/instance.html

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for the connection. From what I see, the nest component is a child component inside the App component. You could test that `<App />` contains `.

```
describe('<App />', () => {
  it('should contain a nest component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find(<Nest />)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Secondly, since the onChange event on the nest component updates the state in the App component, you can also test for state changes since its a behavior you expect.

```
it('should update state', () => {
  //find input and simulate change with say {value: 'new value'} and then
  expect(wrapper.state().value).toBe('newValue');
});
```

I hope this helps.